# How to programmatically post (share) a YouTube video on Facebook Pages?

Tags: ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube, koala

Currently I upload a number of scientific videos directly onto YouTube AND Facebook. I would prefer to simply upload them to YouTube and then share these on a Facebook Page.  The problem I've had hitherto, and thus the reason for the direct uploads, is that I can only get the videos shared onto my user account and they will not post onto the Page that I desire.  I do NOT want these showing up on my user account.

***How can this be done in Ruby (or Ruby on Rails)?***  I'm open to gem suggestions or any other method.

Comment: This is possible with the [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) gem. After fetching a user's info, you can call "#accounts" on the user object to see a list of pages that user has permission to post to and create a new feed object that way. It's not the most straightforward use of the gem, but examples do exist online.

Also, it's possible (and likely) koala has this functionality, however, I'm not familiar with that gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post a [feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) on your facebook account including the youtube video's url.

Famous gem are [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/) and [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph).

Example using Koala

```
fb_api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
fb_api.put_wall_post(message, {:link => youtube_video_url,
                               :description => description,
                               :name => video_title})
```

Comment: Actually have used Koala, however it's not been too successful in this particular scenario with the video to the page.  As a matter of fact I ended up having to switch over to fb_graph due to problems that Koala seemed incapable of overcoming when it came to an integration with Twitter via the FB functionality.  Perhaps it's time to review this again.